# How to turn off auto-accent (e.g. 'e creates é)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I´m running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire S7.

Somehow, I managed to toggle on auto-accenting. That is, when I type **´** then **s** I get **ś**.

¨i = ï

~a = ã

`u = ù  ... etc.

I just toggled this on today accidentally, but I can´t figure out how to turn it off! It´s super annoying to hit the space after the punctuation keys to get the symbol, especially when coding.

I don´t believe itś a problem with my keyboard layout - that hasn´t changed. I must have toggled it on via a keysmush of some kind. I am not using a 'dead key' keyboard layout, either.

This seems like it should be a simple fix, but I´ve googled around and I haven't found a solution! Some posts say that `Ctrl + Shift` usually toggles this function on and off, but that doesn't have any effect for me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edited to add:** I´ve tried every combination of keys that I can think of that might toggle this function on/off, and switched keyboard layouts several times (rebooting each time), to see if that had any effect. No luck! I will really appreciate it if someone can help!

Per [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson)'s post below: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` outputs:

> [('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'us+euro'), ('xkb', 'us+alt-intl'), ('xkb', 'us+intl')]

And `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current` outputs:

> uint32 3

In GUI:
[Screenshot of Keyboard - Text Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5myw.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of the commands `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` and `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Thank you for the response. Done, please see above.

Comment: I'm having the same issue except I only have the single source `[('xkb', 'us')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current keyboard layout is *English (US, international with dead keys)*. So you should switch to the basic *English (US)*. The command line way is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

You may want to check out the [documentation about input sources](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html), including how to switch between them. In your case it sounds as if you don't need any other keyboard layout but *English (US)*, and in that case you may want to open *Text Entry* and remove the other in order to prevent more accidents. ;)

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much, I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me out. :)

Comment: @arokath: Great! Please accept the answer then by clicking the grey tick, so others see that the problem has been solved.